# GitHub Repository Security

Tags: security, github

While using a paid account on github, we currently have a private repository which is forked only by contributors that work within the same network.

What is the best way to ensure that the code remains private? In other words, how can the organization restrict reading/cloning/downloading of the repository (or its forks) by a computer off network?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can control the network access level on github, but you definitely shoud check this permission guide on github: https://help.github.com/en/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization

Comment: You can't do this. Git (not Github) does not have this facility built into it, and because each Git clone is a complete copy of your repository, anybody with a clone of your repo on their laptop can create any number of copies of your repo on other machines or other services like Gitlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a version hosted on github.com, then there's no technical way to restrict access to that private repository based on the network from which the connection comes. If you need that functionality, you'll need to self-host with GitHub Enterprise Server, which is the on-premises version. You can then limit access to that server to only people on your network.

You could also enable SAML single sign-on and only allow access to GitHub if the SAML authentication comes from your network. However, do be aware that once a user has logged in, the SAML session is cached, so a user could log in while on your network and then take their laptop somewhere else and still access things. That also wouldn't prevent actually cloning a repository with a token or a key, however.

If your goal is solely to ensure that the code remains private and you generally trust your employees, you could try techniques like requiring 2FA for all employees, which makes it harder for people to compromise accounts.

Comment: Very clear, thank you for your help. Given that I'd prefer keeping a cloud based solution; Do you know if functionality like IP whilelisting is available on other version control platforms?

Comment: I don't know. Generally the solution for this is to host on premises, because that's the only sure-fire way to prevent access by third parties.